# Invalid connection string when using table adapter

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to use variables in my connection string to a table adapter. The only clean cut method I've seen is the following, however, I'm getting "Invalid Connection string" upon run-time. I'm assuming maybe this can't be done?

```
 Private Sub adaptertest_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'BCPM_DDBODataSet.LTC_FBS' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
LTC_FBSTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=TDOLEDB;Data Source=TDDEV;Persist Security Info=True;User ID={0};Password={1};Default Database=bcpm_ddbo;Session Mode=ANSI;"
Me.LTC_FBSTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BCPM_DDBODataSet.LTC_FBS)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need modify your code to contain the username and password.

Updated code snippet.

```
Private Sub adaptertest_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'BCPM_DDBODataSet.LTC_FBS' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.

Dim DBConnStr as string = "Provider=TDOLEDB;Data Source=TDDEV;Persist Security Info=True;User ID={0};Password={1};Default Database=bcpm_ddbo;Session Mode=ANSI;"

'NOTE: Replace the DBUserName and DBPwd with the actual username and pwd to DB.
DBConnStr = String.Format(DBConnStr,"DBUserName","DBPwd")

LTC_FBSTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = DBConnStr 
Me.LTC_FBSTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BCPM_DDBODataSet.LTC_FBS)
```

For more information on connectionstring, refer [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Comment: I just tried your above example and received the same error on line:LTC_FBSTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = DBConnStr This seems like it should definitely work... There are connection strings defined in my app.config file, but won't this override those? Also - the connection string is correct and works fine when performing a hand coded update/insert query.

Comment: This is a Teradata Backend... Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Needed to fix TD connection string to look like standard SQL to work with table adapter....

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to be providing the user name and password values, hence invalid connection string.

Try

```
LTC_FBSTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = string.format("Provider=TDOLEDB;Data Source=TDDEV;Persist Security Info=True;User ID={0};Password={1};Default Database=bcpm_ddbo;Session Mode=ANSI;" _
,TheActualUserName _
,TheActualPassword)
```

Comment: I have tried with the actual user/pass which i do eventually want as variables and still receive the same error message...  User Id=diw07;Password=hockey4;